# BootStrap - DropDown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to call the basic drop-down function that bootstrap offer, I hooked up a js function, setup links to the js. Tried non js everything doesn't work this is as close as I've got and its still a no go. This is my list -

```
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown" id="accountmenu">  
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Tutorials<b class="caret"></b></a>  
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">  
                        <li><a href="#">PHP</a></li>  
                        <li><a href="#">MySQL</a></li>  
                        <li class="divider"></li>  
                        <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>  
                        <li><a href="#">HTML5</a></li>  
                    </ul>  
                </li>  
          <li><a href="#contact">News</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://MapleEdge.paycraft.co">Shop</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->> Blockquote
```

So it should just work with all the js hooked up but it doesn't you can see the live site here - http://www.epic-pvp.com/

thanks so much I've tried everything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have looked javascript errors - you clearly haven't included `jquery` library on the page..

Twitter bootstrap relies heavily on jQuery and they've documented on [getting started page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/getting-started.html#html-template) that you should include latest version of jQuery in your template for it to work..

Comment: I added it but with no change :(

Comment: You've added it on the bottom of the page, which is valid, but you're using jQuery variables inside the `<head>` tag while your jQuery still hasn't loaded.. You should either move jquery inside the <head> tag or move your custom javascript declarations to the bottom after including jquery..

Answer (score 1):

You include jQuery on line 193 of the HTML.

The first time you try to use jQuery is on line 24 of the HTML.

You can't use it before you load it.

Answer (score 0):

I did mine as shown below.

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li id="theme_selector" class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Theme <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul id="theme" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Amelia</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Cerulean</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Cyborg</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Cosmo</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Darkly</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Flatly</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Lumen</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Simplex</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Slate</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Spacelab</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Superhero</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">United</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Yeti</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Script

```
$('#theme li').click(function () {
   switch_style($(this).text());
        });
```

Works great